# Clearing jQuery animation correctly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

In my code I am animating objects on each carousel item like so:

```
first_text1.fadeTo(textDuration, 1, function(){
    second_text1.fadeTo(textDuration, 1);
});
```

When the slide changes I call the following where `$animations` contains all the objects which have any animation added to them:

```
$animations.stop(true, true);
```

and then I call:

```
$animations.each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

to remove any of the inline CSS which is left by the animations so I can repeat the animations when returning to that slide.

My problem is the style never gets removed from the second callback animation which would be `second_text1` in the above code.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be the selectors in the variables, where some had more than one variable.

E.g.

```
var first_text2 = $('li#region-2 .text-elements h2, li#region-2 .text-elements h3');
var second_text2 = $('li#region-2 .text-elements p');
```

Thee removeAttr function was not working properly on all of the elements in the variable. To fix this I had to call

```
first_text2.each( function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

Apologies for not displaying more code in my question originally!!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing `$animations`, its hard to say why the `second_text1`'s style is not being removed. However, through personal experience, I noticed that the problem with `jQuery(':animated')` is it only finds objects that are in the process of animating.  The moment the animation is complete, the object is no longer consider `:animated`.

The being said, I recommend adding a class to each object you want animated and use that as the selector rather than `$animations`.

So I would make the following changes:

1. Add the class before the animation, in this case `.fadeTo()`

   ```
   first_text1.addClass('animatedClass').fadeTo(textDuration, 1, function(){
       second_text1.addClass('animatedClass').fadeTo(textDuration, 1);
   });
   ```
2. Change `$animations` to the class

   ```
   $('.animatedClass').stop(true, true);

   $('.animatedClass').each(function() {
       $(this).removeAttr('style');
   });
   ```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVjBn/19/

Hope this is what you are looking for.  Let me know if you have any other questions!

Happy coding!

Comment: Not exactly, my fault for not sharing enough code. Still quality answer, +1